# Removing Sparkle from App Store version

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, app-store, sparkle

OK, so I have 2 different builds, an App Store release, and one for my website.

At the end of my Build Phases list, I have a Run Script phase with the following:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "AppStore (Debug)" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "AppStore (Release)"]; then
rm -rf "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH/Sparkle.framework"
fi
```

Which actually deletes the Sparkle framework from its contents.

And when building for `AppStore (Release)`, the final bundle is working fine (no `Sparkle.framework` in the bundle contents whatsoever)

However, when I archive and try to submit to the app store, I'm getting a bunch of errors complaining about the inclusion of Sparkle (+ when I look into the archive, all of a sudden Sparkle is there!)

What's going on? Is my script not being executed when archiving?

Any ideas?

Comment: hm.. Sparke.framework will be deleted, but it will be still linked to project as a library, probably you should remove it from project file too, ah as I understood it's set to optional?

Comment: BTW, I suggest you to create a new Target, for example "YourApp Appstore", and unlink Sparkle there.

Comment: @l0gg3r My current configuration is so complex I can't even believe my own eyes! lol But generally (except for the Archiv-ing) it's working fine. As for this, here's how I got it working: I did everything as usual, by building using my App Store config, and just opened the archive (via Organizer) and manually deleted `Sparkle.framework` (And no, it wasn't being linked, that had already been taken care of). So simple? Yep, so simple. Job done, bundle successfully validated and app currently "waiting for review". (again) :-) *(Whenever it takes me less than 5 hours, I feel like sth is wrong :p)*